# Categorifying the Cauchy kernel as a filtration of $\operatorname*{Sym}\left( F\otimes G\right) $ over any commutative ring

Tags: invariant-theory, determinants, algebraic-combinatorics, young-tableaux, schur-functors

> **Question 1 (short version).** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let
>   $F$ and $G$ be two $R$-modules. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it true that the
>   $n$-th symmetric power $\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{n}\left(  F\otimes
> G\right)  $ has a filtration by $R$-submodules such that the associated graded
>   $R$-module of this filtration is isomorphic to $\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda
> \vdash n}F^{\lambda}\otimes G^{\lambda}$, where the $F^{\lambda}$ and
>   $G^{\lambda}$ are the standard Schur functors (defined below) of $F$ and $G$ ?

**Caveats.** I do **not** require $F$ and $G$ to be free; this is the point of
the question. Also, what I call "standard Schur functors" here is the
"construction in linear algebra" in Section 8.1 of Fulton's *Young tableaux*
book. They may and may not be called Schur functors or Weyl functors
(or something different) in the literature.

> **Question 2.** What is an up-to-date place to learn about Schur functors and
>   their relations (identities, complexes, filtrations etc.) and their
>   applications to characteristic-free invariants from a concrete and
>   combinatorial perspective? I am aware of the
>   [three](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870882900391)
>   [classical](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000187088590115X)
>   [papers](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870888900278) by
>   Akin, Buchsbaum and (partly) Weyman, but I cannot help hoping that there is
>   something more readable around by now. How much of this is covered by
>   [Weyman's *Cohomology of Vector Bundles and
>   Syzygies*](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=0521621976),
>   and where else should I look?

Now for the **long version**.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. I want to understand the "Schur
bifunctor" that sends two $R$-modules $F$ and $G$ to the graded $R$-algebra
$\operatorname*{Sym}\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $. This has two motivations:

- One is that this algebra $\operatorname*{Sym}\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $ is
  a basis-free generalization of the "letterplace algebra" (i.e., the coordinate
  ring of the affine variety of $n\times m$-matrices over $R$); studying it as a
  bifunctor thus generalizes the study of the "letterplace algebra" as a
  bimodule over matrices acting from the left and from the right (and not just
  square matrices). The letterplace algebra has been studied as such a bimodule
  for a while, and various classical results (such as the straigthening rule)
  have come out of this study; this is treated, e.g., in [the famous
  DeConcini/Eisenbud/Procesi
  paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002095858).
  However, letterplace algebras are the particular case when both $F$ and $G$
  are finitely generated free $R$-modules, and the methods for studying them
  tend to strongly rely on this requirement (e.g., they use semistandard bitableaux).
- Another motivation is to categorify the Cauchy kernel identity $\prod
  _{i,j}\dfrac{1}{1-x_{i}y_{j}}=\sum_{\lambda}s_{\lambda}\left(  x\right)
  s_{\lambda}\left(  y\right)  $ for Schur functions (see any text on symmetric
  functions, e.g., Theorem 2.5.1 in
  [Grinberg/Reiner](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/HopfComb-sols.pdf)). Classically, the left hand side is
  categorified as the symmetric algebra $\operatorname*{Sym}\left(  F\otimes
  G\right)  $ for $F$ and $G$ being infinite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector
  spaces, whereas the right hand side is categorified as $\bigoplus
  \limits_{\lambda}F^{\lambda}\otimes G^{\lambda}$ over all partitions $\lambda
  $. Restricting ourselves to the $n$-th graded component, this suggests an
  isomorphism $\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{n}\left(  F\otimes G\right)
  \cong\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda\vdash n}F^{\lambda}\otimes G^{\lambda}$, which
  is indeed the case over a field of characteristic $0$. Over a general
  commutative ring, Section III.1 of
  [Akin/Buchsbaum/Weyman](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870882900391)
  shows that the next best thing holds -- namely, there is an $R$-module
  filtration of $\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{n}\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $
  whose associated graded object is $\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda\vdash
  n}F^{\lambda}\otimes G^{\lambda}$ -- as long as $F$
  and $G$ are finitely-generated free $R$-modules.

Neither of these two motivations motivates the generality in which I want to
work, viz., $F$ and $G$ being arbitrary $R$-modules. It is a matter of idle
curiosity and an attempt to understand the theory better by seeking out its
limits. One important pillar of the theory -- the concept of semistandard
tableaux -- disappears when the freeness of the modules is lost, so I suspect
that a positive answer will require at least some new ideas (or some reduction to the free case).

Let me now go into the details of the filtration. First, let me recall the
definition of the $F^{\lambda}$ and $G^{\lambda}$, in which I follow Section
8.1 of Fulton's *Young tableaux* (but use my own language):

> **Definition.** Let $E$ be any $R$-module. Let $\lambda$ be a partition. Let
>   $\lambda_{1}^{\prime},\lambda_{2}^{\prime},\lambda_{3}^{\prime},\ldots$ be the
>   lengths of the columns of the Young diagram of $\lambda$ (from left to right).
>   Let $\Lambda^{\lambda}E$ be the tensor product $\Lambda^{\lambda_{1}^{\prime}
> }E\otimes\Lambda^{\lambda_{2}^{\prime}}E\otimes\Lambda^{\lambda_{3}^{\prime}
> }E\otimes\cdots$. (The infinite tensor product makes sense, since all but
>   finitely many of its factors are $R$.)
>
> The *cells* of $\lambda$ shall mean the cells of the Young diagram of
>   $\lambda$. An *$E$-tableau of shape $\lambda$* will mean an arbitrary way to fill the
>   cells of $\lambda$ with vectors in $E$. For each $E$-tableau $t$ of shape $\lambda$, we define an element
>   $\left[  t\right]  \in\Lambda^{\lambda}E$ by $\left[  t\right]  =t_{1}
> ^{\wedge}\otimes t_{2}^{\wedge}\otimes t_{3}^{\wedge}\otimes\cdots$, where
>   $t_{i}^{\wedge}$ is the exterior product of the vectors in the $i$-th column
>   of $t$ (from top to bottom).
>
> We define an $R$-submodule $X_{\lambda} E$ of $\Lambda^{\lambda}E$ as follows:
>
> Let $v$ be any $E$-tableau of shape $\lambda$. Let $i$ and $j$ be two positive integers with
>   $i<j$. Choose some set $J$ of cells of the $j$-th column of $\lambda$. If $I$
>   is any set of cells of the $i$-th column of $\lambda$ satisfying $\left\vert
> I\right\vert =\left\vert J\right\vert $, then $\operatorname*{ex}
> \nolimits_{I,J}v$ shall denote the $E$-tableau defined as follows: Switch the
>   entries of $v$ in the cells from $I$ with the entries in the cells from $J$
>   (while preserving their vertical order); leave the remaining entries of $v$
>   unchanged. The resulting $E$-tableau shall be $\operatorname*{ex}
> \nolimits_{I,J}v$. Let $\partial_{i,j,J}v$ be the difference $\left[
> v\right]  -\sum_{I}\left[  \operatorname*{ex}\nolimits_{I,J}v\right]  $, where
>   the sum ranges over all sets $I$ of cells of the $i$-th column of $\lambda$
>   satisfying $\left\vert I\right\vert =\left\vert J\right\vert $.
>
> Now, $X_{\lambda}E$ shall be the $R$-linear span of all differences of the
>   form $\partial_{i,j,J}v$, where $v$ is any $E$-tableau of shape $\lambda$, where $i<j$ and where $J$
>   is a set of cells of the $j$-th column of $\lambda$.
>
> The *Schur module* $E^{\lambda}$ is defined as the quotient $\left(
> \Lambda^{\lambda}E\right)  /\left(  X_{\lambda}E\right)  $. It is clearly
>   functorial in $E$.

Notice that this definition immediately yields a universal property of
$E^{\lambda}$, which is how Fulton defines it.

Now, let $F$ and $G$ be two $R$-modules.

> **Definition.** For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we define the $R$-bilinear map
>   $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot\right\rangle :\left(  \Lambda^{n}F\right)
> \times\left(  \Lambda^{n}G\right)  \rightarrow\operatorname*{Sym}
> \nolimits^{n}\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $ by
>   $$
> \left\langle f_{1}\wedge f_{2}\wedge\cdots\wedge f_{n},g_{1}\wedge g_{2}
> \wedge\cdots\wedge g_{n}\right\rangle =\det\left(  \left(  f_{i}\otimes
> g_{j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)
> $$
>   (where the determinant is taken in the commutative ring $\operatorname*{Sym}
> \left(  F\otimes G\right)  $).
>
> **Definition.** Let $\lambda$ be a partition. Let $\lambda_{1}^{\prime
> },\lambda_{2}^{\prime},\lambda_{3}^{\prime},\ldots$ be the lengths of the
>   columns of the Young diagram of $\lambda$ (from left to right). Define the
>   $R$-bilinear map $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot\right\rangle :\left(
> \Lambda^{\lambda}F\right)  \times\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda}G\right)
> \rightarrow\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{\left\vert \lambda\right\vert
> }\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $ by
>   $$
> \left\langle f_{1}\otimes f_{2}\otimes f_{3}\otimes\cdots,g_{1}\otimes
> g_{2}\otimes g_{3}\otimes\cdots\right\rangle =\prod_{i\geq1}\left\langle
> f_{i},g_{i}\right\rangle
> $$
>   (where the $f_{i}$ and the $g_{i}$ are now exterior products themselves, not
>   just vectors). As usual, we define $\left\langle \Lambda^{\lambda}
> F,\Lambda^{\lambda}G\right\rangle $ as the $R$-submodule of
>   $\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{\left\vert \lambda\right\vert }\left(  F\otimes
> G\right)  $ spanned by the image of this map $\left\langle \cdot
> ,\cdot\right\rangle :\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda}F\right)  \times\left(
> \Lambda^{\lambda}G\right)  \rightarrow\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{\left\vert
> \lambda\right\vert }\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $.

Now, let us fix an $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Order all the partitions of $n$ in
lexicographic order. (It is possible to replace the lexicographic order here
by the finer dominance order, but this would complicate the concept of a
filtration). For every partition $\lambda$ of $n$, we let $M_{\lambda}$ be the
$R$-submodule $\sum\limits_{\substack{\gamma\vdash n;\\\gamma\geq\lambda
}}\left\langle \Lambda^{\gamma}F,\Lambda^{\gamma}G\right\rangle $ of
$\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{n}\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $. Since the
lexicographic order is a total order, we thus can regard $\left(  M_{\lambda
}\right)  _{\lambda\vdash n}$ as a filtration of $\operatorname*{Sym}
\nolimits^{n}\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $, and we can wonder what its
associated graded $R$-module is.

For each $\lambda\vdash n$, we let $\dot{M}_{\lambda}$ be the $R$-submodule
$\sum\limits_{\substack{\gamma\vdash n;\\\gamma>\lambda}}\left\langle
\Lambda^{\gamma}F,\Lambda^{\gamma}G\right\rangle $ of $\operatorname*{Sym}
\nolimits^{n}\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $. (If $\lambda=\left(  n\right)  $,
then this is $0$; otherwise, it is $M_{\lambda^{\circ}}$, where $\lambda
^{\circ}$ is the next-higher partition of $n$ after $\lambda$ in the
lexicographic order.) Then, the associated graded $R$-module of the filtration
$\left(  M_{\lambda}\right)  _{\lambda\vdash n}$ is $\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda
\vdash n}M_{\lambda}/\dot{M}_{\lambda}$.

Now, for each $\lambda\vdash n$, the $R$-bilinear map $\left\langle
\cdot,\cdot\right\rangle :\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda}F\right)  \times\left(
\Lambda^{\lambda}G\right)  \rightarrow\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{n}\left(
F\otimes G\right)  $ gives rise to an $R$-linear map $\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda
}F\right)  \otimes\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda}G\right)  \rightarrow
\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{n}\left(  F\otimes G\right)  $, which in turn
gives rise to a surjective $R$-linear map $F^{\lambda}\otimes G^{\lambda
}\rightarrow M_{\lambda}/\dot{M}_{\lambda}$. (To see this, we observe that the
$R$-linear map $\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda}F\right)  \otimes\left(
\Lambda^{\lambda}G\right)  \rightarrow\operatorname*{Sym}\nolimits^{n}\left(
F\otimes G\right)  $ has image contained in $M_{\lambda}$, so it can be regarded as a
map $\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda}F\right)  \otimes\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda
}G\right)  \rightarrow M_{\lambda}$; and when we compose this map with
the projection $M_{\lambda}\rightarrow M_{\lambda}/\dot{M}_{\lambda}$, the
resulting map $\left(  \Lambda^{\lambda}F\right)  \otimes\left(  \Lambda
^{\lambda}G\right)  \rightarrow M_{\lambda}/\dot{M}_{\lambda}$ factors through
$F^{\lambda}\otimes G^{\lambda}$. The factoring follows from a determinant identity that mimics the generators of $X_{\lambda}F$ and $X_{\lambda}G$. Alternately, it can probably be derived from the Garnir relations for determinants, but this would require a different definition of the $E^\lambda$.)

When $F$ and $G$ are free $R$-modules of finite rank, this surjective
$R$-linear map $F^{\lambda}\otimes G^{\lambda}\rightarrow M_{\lambda}/\dot
{M}_{\lambda}$ is actually an isomorphism, and this yields that the associated
graded $R$-module of the filtration $\left(  M_{\lambda}\right)
_{\lambda\vdash n}$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda\vdash
n}F^{\lambda}\otimes G^{\lambda}$.

> **Question 1 (precise form).** Is this true for arbitrary $F$ and $G$ ?